# How to change company domain name in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have made an application using Flutter. However, now I want to change the domain name I initially used while creating the application. How can I do that?

Most of the answers on Stackoverflow explain how to change package name and domain name in normal Android Studio projects (not for Flutter projects).

Answer (score 8):

For Android project (android folder of Flutter project):

- Change **applicationId** in *android/app/build.gradle*;
- Change **package** attribute in **manifest** tag in *android/app/src/XX/AndroidManifest.xml*, where XX is a build type (main, debug, profile);
- Change package name in your *MainActivity.java* (or .kt) (also rename directory).

For iOS project (ios folder of Flutter project):

- Change **PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER** for 3 buildSettings (debug,
  release, profile) in *ios/Runner.pbxproj* (you can open it in xcode or
  just as text).
- Change value for key **CFBundleName** in *ios/Runner/Info.plist*

Answer (score 1):

To change your domain name and to save some headaches, redo iOS and Android Folders:

If your project doesn't have android or iOS specific files like

> GoogleService-Info.plist

or

> google-services.json

you could safely delete both ios and android folder from your project root directory, just have in mind all the stuff you'd need to set up later and then run in the project root directory the following command

```
flutter create . --org com.foo.bar
```

then it will regenerate both ios and android projects configured with your desired domain(com.foo.bar) and will add your project name after the domain (com.foo.bar.you_project_name); Your build.gradle will look something like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.foo.bar.YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

If your iOS or Android project contain specific files, you could just back up them, then do the above steps and finally add up the files to the project or generate new files.. I find these steps more convenient and less prune to mistakes than having to search variables in different files within the project and change directory names,

Pros:
Faster, Easier than changing names, no need to fix in-code packages imports & folders because they're generated automatically,  less prone to make mistakes

Cons:
building the projects might use old gradle&kotlin versions so probably you need to update these, need to declare dependencies i.e firebase, need to restore specific files

Answer (score 0):

I picked to try Casareafer's suggested approach. Here is how I did it my way while my project had `firebase` as well. That should work for anyone. Make sure you have proper access to the connected `firebase` account.

- Delete `android` and `ios` directories.
- Delete `pubspec.lock` file.
- Run the following command:

```
flutter create . --org com.yourdomain --platform ios,android
```

It will create fresh android and ios directories keeping all the rest same. You're done with your updated domain.

Now you have to restore the services like `firebase`. Specifically for firebase it's pretty simple. Ensure that you have firebase CLI and flutterfire CLI installed [Check the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

- Disconnect the flutter app from the existing firebase project from the firebase console > project > project settings > Your apps > delete both android and ios.
- Run the following command and choose your project. It should automatically connect your project to the firebase.

```
flutterfire configure
```

- Now run the app by

```
flutter run
```

If you face any issues try using:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

and then

```
flutter run
```